# my facebook integration in android not working

Tags: android, facebook

i had used the sample app for posting message on wall in android from site https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.

but what's happening is when my phone contains any other facebook app, it doesn't work. Otherwise it work's fine. kindly help me on this.

Comment: which Facebook SDK version are you using? the SDK updates quite often and watch out for obsoleted functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is if we have already installed any facebook application in our device which are upgraded versions than we are using our application will not work...If we uninstall the facebook applications in our device it will work...and there is also another way to work our application and other facebook application in our device by following steps::: if u r using eclipse then goto

Windows>Preferences>Android>Build and get the path of the debug keystore

now open terminal and run the following command

```
keytool -export -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "debug keystore path" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```

it will ask for the password then enter android as ur password Now add the HASH KEY to your Facebook API configuration located @ http://www.facebook.com/developers/ under EDIT SETTINGS / Mobile and Devices screen.

Now i was able to run my application on HTC device

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just used -1 for the activity code in authorize method. This forces the user to login, Disabling the SSO